# How to handle utf-8 encoded text in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, character-encoding

I am trying to send text from a served HTML form to the server. My problem is that the text appears to still be somewhat encoded in utf8? I'm not sure how to decode the text back in to it's original form?

**html file**

```
var body = '<html>'+
'<head>'+
'<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; '+
'charset=UTF-8" />'+
'</head>'+
'<body>'+
'<form action="/upload" method="post">'+  //sends POST req to /upload
'<textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>'+
'<input type="submit" value="Submit text" />'+
'</form>'+
'</body>'+
'</html>';
```

**server.js**

```
    req.setEncoding('utf8');

    var postData = [];
    req.on('data', function(postDataChunk) {
     // called when a new chunk of data was received
     postData.push(postDataChunk);
     console.log('Recieved POST data chunk: "'+ postDataChunk + '"');
    });

    req.addListener('end', function() {
    // called when all chunks of data have been received
    var text = decoder.write(postData);
    console.log("all Data arrived: " + text);

    route(pathname, handle, res, text);
    });
```

prints out: "all Data arrived: text=blah+blah+blah%21"

I've tried setting the content header of the response to UTF-8, and the StringDecoder as below, but neither seem to do anything.

Comment: So we're clear, what were you expecting it to give? The content you are getting back (`text=blah+blah+blah%21`), is utf8 text, but since you submitted it via a form, it is sent to the server encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Generally you'd decode this with something like [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

Comment: Ah, so forms have their own encoding. I was expecting it to give back "blah blah blah!". Looked up and read http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1, now I'll go look into body-parser. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, the text encoding is independent of how the values for a form are represented. There needs to be some way for the server to know what values map to which keys though, since forms might not only have a single `text` field.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
var querystring = require("querystring")

var text = querystring.parse(postData).text;
console.log("all Data arrived: " + text);
```

I don't know exactly if this postData.push works. As an alternative you can also try:

```
var postData = "";
req.on('data', function(postDataChunk) {
  postData += postDataChunk;
```